# Fast way to add subtitles to mkv file?

Tags: video

Can I add subtitles to an mkv file without creating a new file?

I have a shared storage connected to my router and the combined read and write transfer speed is around 10mb/s. If I have an 8gb 1080p mkv file and I add subtitles to it using mkvmerge, it starts creating a new output file and it's reading with 5mb/s and writing with the same speed. It takes about half an hour to add 70kb subtitles to a movie and a lot of unnecessary disk usage. Is there no way for this to be avoided?

Comment: subtitles can exits as **seperate file** (like *.srt, *.sub).many players can detect it automatically when in same folder and named correctly.

Comment: My router is running a media server and I'm watching the movies on my TV, but I don't see the subtitles unless they are inside the mkv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. Subtitles are stored in `mkv` file as attachments, and those are [located](https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvmerge.html#mkvmerge.file_layout) near the beginning of the file, before the audio/video data:

```
[EBML head] [segment {meta seek #1} [segment information] [track information] {attachments} {chapters} [cluster 1] {cluster 2} ... {cluster n} {cues} {meta seek #2} {tags}]
```

When you insert new content into a file, everything past the insertion point has to be overwritten in order to accommodate new data.